# firebase firestore usage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to know how the way of firestore quotas works on Read/Write/Delete while im using my app.
for example if i have a collection that has 5 documents...if i deleted the collection (which includes 5 docs) it will withdraw from my delete quota 5 from 20k? (i'm using spark plan) and for the read quote...if i retrieved that collection which has 5 docs...eachtime i retrieve that collection it will withdraw 5 from 50k reads ? for example if i created a button that when i click on it...it will call a function that retrieve those 5 docs...so if clicked on the button twice...it will withdraw me 10 from 50k ?

is that the way it works ? and how write quota works ?

Comment: Yes. The docs have a great [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example#costs-breakdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

Every read, write and delete counts as one operation. Example: if you retrieve a collection with 5 documents, it will count as 5 read operations. If you create, update or increment 5 documents, it will count as 5 write operations. Same for delete, each doc delete is one operation.

Note: you pay for the update operation even if the updated data is the same as the existing data in the document. Since the write operation is more expensive than the read operation, if you have doubt that the data may be similar you can check if the data has actually changed before sending an update request. You can achieve this by comparing the new data with the existing data on the client-side and only sending an update request if there are changes to be made